# RMSProp Squared Gradients

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, gradient-descent

In the RMSProp algorithm (And similar algorithms) that are used in Machine Learning in the subject of Adaptive Learning Rates, the squares of the gradients are used in the algorithm step.

Is there motivation for why the squares of the gradients are used?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The squares are only to damp out the oscillations by first squaring the previous gradients and then taking the root of it. It is kind of like taking the absolute value of the previous gradients and hence what matters is mainly the magnitude.

Comment: Can you please give an example of how squares dumps out the oscillations ?